# jQuery.each() doesn't iterate object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using latest jQuery 3.6.0 I can't figure out why the object is not iterated.

```
json = [{"id":9,"brand_id":"","supplier_id":"","code":"","sku":"item","mpn":"","gtin":"","taric":"","image":"","quantity":100,"quantity_unit_id":1,"ordered":0,"weight":0,"weight_unit":"kg","length":0,"width":0,"height":0,"length_unit":"cm"}];

$.each(json, function(i) {
  $.each(json[i], function(key, value) {
    console.log(key, value);
    alert('Does not come this far');
  });
});
```

This object however works:

```
json = [{"foo":"bar", "this": "that"}];
```

Can anyone spot the obvious?
https://jsfiddle.net/qnbwm0ej/

Comment: it's because `json[i]` is not an array, so that it can't be iterateable

Comment: @NekoMi: Sure can, jQuery.each() supports objects (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-object-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.keys()

+Edited for the real "value" :)

```
    json = [{"id":9,"brand_id":"","supplier_id":"","code":"","sku":"item","mpn":"","gtin":"","taric":"","image":"","quantity":100,"quantity_unit_id":1,"ordered":0,"weight":0,"weight_unit":"kg","length":0,"width":0,"height":0,"length_unit":"cm"}];

$.each(json, function(i) {
  console.log(json[i]);

  $.each(Object.keys(json[i]), function(key, value) {
    console.log(value, json[i][value]);
  });
});
```

++Edit

It's not going to iterate each key-value because you added property `"length":0`. If you add a `"length":0` property to the second object you posted, it won't work just like the first object. You can check why and how the jquery.each works from [here line 238](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a684e6ba836f7c553968d7d026ed7941e1a612d8/src/core.js#L238)

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/2nmwt1q6/) is some tests for the custom `length` property in objects.

Comment: No that doesn't populate the real "value"

Comment: @tim so jquery.each is working perfect, isn't it? edited the answer for the real "value".

Comment: Any idea why [{"foo":"bar", "this": "that"}] works in my example and not the first object? I feel this is a workaround.

Comment: @tim It's because you added property `"length":0` into the object. If you add a `length:0` property to the second object you posted, it won't work just like the first object. You can check how the jquery.each works from [here line 238](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/core.js)

Comment: @Jejun Nice catch on the `length`!

Comment: @Jejun Wow I would never have figured that out. Nicely spotted!!

Comment: I created an issue ticket for jQuery with this. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4874

Comment: @tim Might seem a bit strange but isn't totally uncommon. `Array.from({length:3}, (_,i)=>i+1)// returns [ 1, 2, 3 ]`. That is also by design

Comment: @charlietfl Strange indeed :)

Comment: @tim The Array.from() docs specify either an iterable or object with length property also. I read the github reply so essentially the same thing

Comment: I support @tim and think this issue needs to be fixed... has lots of possibilities to make mistakes like this one even if it is by design. It looks like an easter egg or a trap card for jQuery users

Answer (score 0):

Convert all the integer value to string as below.

```
json = [{"id":"9","brand_id":"","supplier_id":"","code":"","sku":"item","mpn":"","gtin":"","taric":"","image":"","quantity":"100","quantity_unit_id":"1","ordered":"0","weight":"0","weight_unit":"kg","length":"0","width":"0","height":"0","length_unit":"cm"}];

$.each(json, function(index,jsonObject){
    console.log(jsonObject);
    $.each(jsonObject, function(key,val){
        console.log(key, val);
    });
});
```

If you do not want to change the data. Please use for...in loop.

```
json = [{"id":9,"brand_id":"","supplier_id":"","code":"","sku":"item","mpn":"","gtin":"","taric":"","image":"","quantity":100,"quantity_unit_id":1,"ordered":0,"weight":0,"weight_unit":"kg","length":0,"width":0,"height":0,"length_unit":"cm"}];
$.each(json, function(index,jsonObject){
    console.log(jsonObject);
  for(var key in jsonObject) {
     console.log(key, jsonObject[key]); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is absolutely not correct. Numbers are perfectly valid json values. In addition when it is assigned to a variable it is not even json. What is displayed in question is a javscript array of objects

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl. I understand, numbers are valid json value but what could be the reason why it doesn't work if we use number as the value and works if we just replace numbers with string?

Comment: The reason seems to be that jQuery.each() goes bananas if there is a property named length.